# Kinesis group video chat (Like zoom) Javascript

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, webrtc, video-streaming, amazon-kinesis

I am using AWS Kinesis, and everything is working well for 1 on 1.  I have 1 Master, 1 Viewer and both can see the other without issue.

If a 3rd person joins as a viewer, the master can see the new viewer, but the initial viewer cannot.  I am not sure how to achieve this as I can only have 1 master per signaling channel, and they are the only ones who can communicate with multiple viewers.  I need the viewers to be able to talk to each other too.

I tried creating a master and viewer for each individual (Concept was they if everytime a viewer joined the master would see the video stream), but due to 1 master per channel on the 1 of the masters was notified to add the new stream.

```
peerConnection.addEventListener("track", async event => {
            if (
              !master.remoteStreams.includes(
                event.streams[event.streams.length - 1]
              )
        ) {
          const remoteView = await parentThis.createVideo();
      
          master.remoteStreams.push(
            event.streams[event.streams.length - 1]
          );
          remoteView.srcObject = event.streams[event.streams.length - 1];
            }
});`
```